# Explicitly Control order of ng-model objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say you have some inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.name">
<input type="text" ng-model="user.phone">
<input type="text" ng-model="user.email">
```

If I output the model, many times the order of the model is apparently random, especially with complicated dynamically generated forms from a database (the above models are over-simplified for the purposes of this question).

So for example:

`{{user}}`

Will usually output in a random order like this:

```
{
 phone: '8888888888',
 email: 'email@domain.com',
 name: 'persons name'
}
```

My question is, how do I explicitly control the order of the elements inside of the object?  Something like this would work perfect: `<input type="text" ng-model="user.name" model-position="1">`

Comment: javascript objects have no order. What are you needing to do that requires order?

Comment: That's not exactly true. According to the spec, object keys do not have an order, but in just about all implementations of JS, the object key order is the same as the order in which they were added.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the object before using it. So javascript will keep the original order.

```
// controller code
$scope.user = {
    name: ''
    phone: '',
    email: ''
};
```

But if you have a dynamic generated object, you must regenerate the object with your desired order.

Comment: This should work. Or just use `ng-init="user = user || {name: null, phone: null, email: null}"` somewhere in the parent of the `<input>` fields.

Comment: @bhantol that isn't what ng-init is for as per docs. Don't move controller functionality to the view

Comment: You are right `ng-init` can be abused controllers are better for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to guarantee an order for your object keys and values is to specify it yourself. In general the best thing to do is to convert your object into an array of key/value pairs and use a filter to ensure that it gets displayed that way. Like so:

```
angular.filter('specialFilter', function(object) {
  return Object.keys(object).sort().map(key => ({key: key, value: object[key] }) );
})
```

And then you can use it in a template like this:

```
{{user | special}}
```

If you want to display the user object properly in a nice, readable format, then you will need to do something a bit fancier, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: You can't control the order here. Just ensures a certain consistent order.

Comment: You can control it any way that you want. You just need to tweak your filter appropriately. And the OP was asking about consistency, not about having full control.